# How to change spring.datasource.url during runtime dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following db config in spring:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost/my_schema1
```

Question: how can I change the url pointing to `my_schema2` dynamically during runtime? Is it possible to reset and reinitialize the database bean?

/edit: I found `AbstractRoutingDataSource` could be the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

why would you want to do this?  Why not add multiple datasources and use Spring profiles to choose which one you want to turn "on" or "off" OR just connect to both databases and use runtime logic to see which `datasource` you want to use.

In the past I've created proxy's to do something like this, but I feel as though that might be overkill for something like this.

Comment: Well, it is possible to change profiles during runtime? I have to connect to a db which has 2 instances, one active and one passive. The state changes every few hours, so I have to redirect my full application to the other db every couple of hours.

Comment: Just connect to both.  It's easy to do with Spring.

Comment: Yes, I found now that `AbstractRoutingDataSource` is the solution